# Zilog Z80 - How to use Interrupt mode 1 (IM 1 Instruction)

Tags: interrupt, mode, z80

I want to use IM 1 interrupt mode on Z80.

In Interrupt mode 1 processor jumps to 38h address in memory(am I right?) and then continues interrupt. How can I specify this in my code?
I have read about:

> defs [,] ds [,]  This pseudo
>   instruction inserts a block of  bytes into the code segment

I need some sample source code.

Kind Regards

Rafał R.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified what Assembler you are using. Also, are you running an actual Z80 chip or a virtual machine? (My first assembly language experience was hand-coded hex on a Z80)

Comment: Oh, thats a hard question. My Z80 is emulated or implemented on dedicated FPGA chip. I use one of z88dk or rather z80asm, i dont know if this is a right name. I use NO-ICE environment to run my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I don't have a Z80 in front of me.

Referencing: [Z80asm directives](http://www.nongnu.org/z80asm/directives.html)

Use org to 'manually' locate  a 'function' at a specified address.
So, to write an IM1 handler:

```
org 0x38
; IM1 handler 
ld a, 100 ; ... whatever
ret
```

Also, I'm not sure of your normal starting address is, but the original Z80s started at location 0. If this is the case you should JMP past the 0x38 handler *very* early in your code. (You only have 56 bytes to play with)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks TomZ! My starting is 1800h (NoICE produces his code in 0-1800).

Comment: Gosh, I was super slow. But would it not be normal to re-enable interrupts before returning?

Comment: One last detail: the RETI instruction was designed to allow certain Z80 support chips to recognize that the Z80 had just finished handling an interrupt. I really have no idea if that is applicable to your solution. Here is a link to more detail: http://www.z80.info/z80_faq.htm#Q-13

Comment: +1 Tommy. You're right about EI. Haven't even thought about Z80 code in decades...

Comment: RETI's also good because it copies IFF2 to IFF1 on exit, which has the effect of re-enabling interrupts if you're exiting from an NMI (as, unlike IRQs, those reset only IFF1 on entry) — so you can do a complete response to them a little faster and a little more neatly. @TomZ: as is probably obvious, I've been working with one very recently indeed...

Answer (score 2):

In IM 1, upon spotting a pending interrupt (which is sampled on the rising edge of the last cycle before the end of an opcode; the IRQ line is just sampled, unlike NMI) IFF1 and 2 are cleared and an `RST 38h` is executed. So you should end up with the PC at 0x38, interrupts disabled and the old program counter on the top of the stack. You'll want to do whatever you have to do to respond to the interrupt, then perform an `EI, RET` or `EI, RETI` (there being no difference here because the two IFF flags have the same value following the interrupt acknowledge).

On a Z80 the PC is set to 0 upon power up or reset so probably you already have some control over the code down at that end of memory. Exact syntax depends on your assembler, but you probably want something like:

```
org 0

; setup initial state here, probably JP somewhere at the end
; possibly squeeze in another routine if you've the space

org 0x38
; respond to interrupt
EI
RET
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what to do when you are not starting from 0h:

```
org 1800h
START: ;Do the start, but It can't take more than 38 instructions
LD SP, 0x2000 ;Initialize SP!
JP MAIN ;Continue to rest of the program

ds 0x1838-$,0 ;Allocate block of memory for interrupt handler
INT:
  ;interrupt sub
  LD E, 0
  LD A, E
  OUT (066), A
  EI
  RETI

ds 0x1840-$,0 ;Alloc space for the rest of program.
MAIN:
  ;Rest of program here
```

As far as you make it like this, processor will put the JP 01838h instruction at the address 038h. 
So the handler is right. Also, remember to initialize stack pointer. If you doesnt, you will not be able to return from interrupt handler to program.